# executing multiple models in tensorflow with a single session

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, neural-network

I'm trying to run several models of neural networks in tensorflow in parallel, each model is independent of the rest.  It is necessary to create a session for each of the executions I launch with tensorflow or I could reuse the same session for each of the models ?. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session is linked to a specific Tensorflow `Graph` instance. If you want to have one session for all, you need to put all your models in the same graph. This may cause you naming problems for tensors and is IMO generally a bad idea (you should keep things that are not related to each other separate).

Having everything in the same graph also raises your model's resources requirements (you always load everything even if you run only a sub-graph), which is another reason to split things in independent graphs. With independent graphs, you'll have to use multiple sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so do you think it would be a good configuration in tensorflow to have a single graph with different sessions for each of the models I'm going to run?

Comment: No, that would be the worst one. If you have N sessions, you'd load all models N times and only use one per session.

Comment: So you recommend me to have a graph for each of the independent models and a single session for each graph? Note that I will finally run 480 models in parallel.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would implement it. I don't know how much is a Session's overhead, so you might need to benchmark a bit. If that's too many, you might group together some of the models and have an "intermediate" solution.