# How to run multiple classification models (keras, caffe, etc) in a single tensorflow session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to run a object detection model (SSD+Inceptionv2) and getting bounding boxes as result. After getting the bounding boxes from a frame, later that cropped images should be passes through different classification models (which were trained on different libraries like keras and caffe) and get prediction results.

Here I am getting bounding boxes from object detection model in a tensorflow session and when trying to use any other models predict method, that predict method is expecting tensoflow object detection input by default. Because of this classification models predict method is not working.

Any idea on how to run different classification models on object detection output bounding boxes (cropped images)?

Answer (score 0):

A session is linked to a specific Tensorflow Graph instance. If you want to have one session for all, you need to put all your models in the same graph. This may cause you naming problems for tensors and is IMO generally a bad idea (you should keep things that are not related to each other separate).

Having everything in the same graph also raises your model's resources requirements (you always load everything even if you run only a sub-graph), which is another reason to split things in independent graphs. With independent graphs, you'll have to use multiple sessions.

[Please refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946751/executing-multiple-models-in-tensorflow-with-a-single-session)